# Android Scrollviewer not scrolling inside Relative Layout with other elements

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, mono

If there was an identical question, I was unable to find it. Most posts did not include properly set up layouts inside of a scrollviewer.

In the following I am unable to have the linear layout scroll that is the child of the scroll viewer. I have obscured some of the id's and names - which are not relevant. Everything outside of the scrolling appears to work as expected.

```
<RelativeLayout
                p1:minWidth="25px"
                p1:minHeight="25px"
                p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:id="@+id/rl_DisplayOutter">
                <TableLayout
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:stretchColumns="*"
                    p1:shrinkColumns="*"
                    p1:id="@+id/tl_tableHeader">
                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                            p1:text="Date"
                            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            p1:id="@+id/tv_date"
                            p1:layout_margin="1dp"
                            p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            p1:textSize="18dp"
                            p1:layout_width="100dp"
                            p1:textStyle="bold" />
                        <TextView
                            p1:text="Time"
                            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            p1:id="@+id/tv_time"
                            p1:layout_margin="1dp"
                            p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            p1:textSize="18dp"
                            p1:layout_width="100dp"
                            p1:textStyle="bold" />
                        <TextView
                            p1:text="Client/User"
                            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            p1:id="@+id/tv_client"
                            p1:layout_margin="1dp"
                            p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            p1:textSize="18dp"
                            p1:layout_width="130dp"
                            p1:textStyle="bold" />
                        <TextView
                            p1:text="Summary"
                            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            p1:id="@+id/tv_summary"
                            p1:layout_margin="1dp"
                            p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            p1:textSize="18dp"
                            p1:layout_width="250dp"
                            p1:textStyle="bold" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
                <ScrollView
                    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="0dp"
                    p1:id="@+id/sv_scrollNoifHome"
                    p1:fadeScrollbars="false"
                    p1:layout_above="@+id/rl_notification" 
                    p1:layout_below="@id/tl_tableHeader"
                    p1:fillViewport="true"
                    p1:focusable="true">
                    <LinearLayout
                        p1:minWidth="25px"
                        p1:minHeight="25px"
                        p1:orientation="vertical"
                        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        p1:id="@+id/ll_llSamplehome" />
                </ScrollView>
                <RelativeLayout
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/rl_Buttons"
                    p1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    p1:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
                    <Button
                        p1:text="Acknowledge"
                        p1:layout_width="150dp"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:id="@+id/btn_acknowledge" />
                    <Button
                        p1:text="Review Later"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_acknowledge"
                        p1:id="@+id/btn_reviewLater"
                        p1:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
                    <Button
                        p1:text="Take Me There"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_reviewLater"
                        p1:id="@+id/btn_takeMeThere"
                        p1:visibility="gone"
                        p1:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
                    <Button
                        p1:text="Close"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_takeMeThere"
                        p1:id="@+id/btn_close"
                        p1:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
                  </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Is someone able to point me in the right direction in terms of what layout or other changes I might make tot his layout to achieve a scrollable linear layout inside of a scrollviewer as a nested element of the overall relative layout?

Side Note: The contents are added to a listview and assigned via a custom adapter to the linear layout - there are hundreds of items so the contents are certainly "scrollable". I also note that the scroll bar itself does show up initially when the layout loads - indicating it has wrapped the linear layout and should/could be scrollable. However any attempt to scroll does not work, and the contents of the layout remain fixed.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want your LinearLayout to have the height of fill_parent since the idea of a ScrollView is as the child view wraps it's contents you want to be able to scroll through it.

> To understand this result, you must remember that
>   android:layout_height=”fill_parent” means “set the height to the
>   height of the parent.” This is obviously not what you want when using
>   a ScrollView. After all, the ScrollView would become useless if its
>   content was always as tall as itself.

source: [ScrollView's handy tricks](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Another thing, I don't see your ListView you are talking about, so I'm assuming you are talking about adding it dynamically? Why not define it in your XML layout, and rid yourself of the ScrollView since a ListView is scrollable anyways. I'll change my answer once you are able to respond on that, but if this is this is the case, I suggest replacing the ScrollView with just the ListView.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I added the listview in XML and used the scrolling properties of the listview itself instead. This worked like a charm. I appreciate your time in assisting me to resolve this matter.  Many thanks!